# How to retain terminal colors inside the Vim terminal (-NOT- in GVim)?

Tags: colorscheme, terminal-buffer

My default terminal look:

[image]

will turn into this in the Vim terminal:

[image]

It's not a huge deal, but the former is easier on my eyes - and this doesn't happen on my other box... Tried to compare configurations but everything seems the same and `source`ing my `.bashrc` does not help either..

**Update**: The in-vim terminal colorscheme actually changes depending on what the active buffer was when it was opened.

Comment: `:help g:terminal_ansi_colors` or something like that

Comment: Never even heard of this but will look into it ASAP. Thanks!